# Check version/if installed PROJ4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, geos, proj

I'm really new in working with Geospatial Libraries and I was able to install GDAL and PostGIS already. I just wanted to check if I was really able to include the packages GEOS and PROJ4 that is a requirement for PostGIS.

What command lines should I type in to check their versions or if they are installed?

I just need the proj4 checking:

> PostGreSQL version : `$ psql --version`
>
> PostGIS version : Connect to your database, `=# SELECT PostGIS_full_version();`
>
> GDAL version: `$ gdal-info --version`
>
> GEOS version: `$ geos-config --version`

Comment: When I run `=# SELECT PostGIS_full_version();` as you have above, it displays the installed GEOS, PROJ and GDAL versions (among other info).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recommend using `pkg-config` if you can as it allows you to query

- if a library is installed
- what version is installed
- whether the version passes a *minimum version required* comparison

and actually just detailed all of that in a comment to the [sf repo](https://github.com/edzer/sfr/issues/36#issuecomment-256614907) which is also in the geo-spatial space.

Quoting:

```
edd@max:~$ pkg-config --atleast-version=2.1.0 gdal && echo "Yes we are good"
edd@max:~$ pkg-config --atleast-version=2.1.0 gdal || echo "Insufficient"
Insufficient
edd@max:~$
```

I don't have `proj4` installed so I can't illustrate that.

*Edit:* I spoke too soon -- I do have it:

```
edd@max:~$ pkg-config --modversion proj
4.9.2
edd@max:~$ pkg-config --atleast-version=4.9.0 proj && echo "Yes"
Yes
edd@max:~$
```

Comment: Just to add, with the release of version 5 __PROJ.4__ was renamed to just __PROJ__.

Answer (score 6):

To add to the OP's list of commands: Typing just `proj` in the command line will also give you the installed version of the [PROJ](https://proj.org/) library.